# addOnAdapterChangeListener in ViewPager cannot be applied to OnPageChangeListener

Tags: android

I have this error in Viewpager adapter:

> addOnAdapterChangeListener in ViewPager cannot be applied to
>   OnPageChangeListener.
>
> **addOnAdapterChangeListener (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnAdapterChangeListener) in
>   ViewPager cannot be applied to (anonymous
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
>   **

[image]

```
package com.example.asierra.onesnap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import com.example.asierra.onesnap.adapter.MainPageAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      final View background = findViewById(R.id.am_background_view);
      final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) 
      findViewById(R.id.am_view_pager);
      MainPageAdapter adapter = new 
      MainPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
      viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    final int primaryColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimary);
    final int accentC olor =  ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent);
    int darkColor =  ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimaryDark);

    viewPager.addOnAdapterChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){


        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change addOnAdapterChangeListener to addOnPageChangeListener.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)